# formatting copied cells blank when no value, even with date, number or formula

Tags: excel, formatting

I try to copy data from sheet 1 to sheet 2  and when there is no value to copy from sheet 1 I would like to leave the cells in sheet 2 blank. 
This works fine with custom formatting : "0;-0;;@".
However when there is a date, number or formula involved the cells get a value because they already have a format.

I tried to build up custom format with more conditions but that didn't work for me. It seems there can be only one format condition in a cell...?

m/d/yyyy, 0;-0;;@,

The error message from excel tells me to use the already the available formats.

Comment: You can use paste special and paste only formulas

Comment: @usmanhaq, yes, but that's something I need to do manually every time. I need this manually....do you have a solution for that?